# EmrOptimizedSparkSqlParquetOutputCommitter not found

Tags: scala, amazon-emr, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to enable the EmrOptimizedSparkSqlParquetOutputCommitter by following the steps outlined in:

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-committer-reqs.html

I am using EMR version 5.23.0

I have set the following configuration options according to the docs (explicitly stating the config values even though some are the default values):

```
.config("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet", "true")
.config("spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class", "com.amazon.emr.committer.EmrOptimizedSparkSqlParquetOutputCommitter")
.config("spark.sql.sources.commitProtocolClass", "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SQLHadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol")
.config("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "static")
.config("spark.sql.parquet.fs.optimized.committer.optimization-enabled", "true")
```

and have the following depedencies in my spark (scala) application

```
"com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.11.598" % "provided"
"com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-s3" % "1.11.598"
```

However when deploying the application I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Class com.amazon.emr.committer.EmrOptimizedSparkSqlParquetOutputCommitter not found
```

I have been unable to find a reference anywhere to which library this committer lives. Therefore I'm guessing that it lives in one of the above aws java sdk depdendencies. Am I missing a dependency? Also, is the spark application the correct place to provide this committer class? Thanks!

**Edit**:

Also tried adding the `aws-java-sdk-emr` dependency as suggested by @Lamanus, but the same error is thrown.

I've come across https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java, fortunately the java sdk is open source. I see no reference to `EmrOptimizedSparkSqlParquetOutputCommitter` which suggests to me that this should be provided to/by the cluster.

Comment: I think that is the default setting and so you don't need to specify. `spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class` must be set to `com.amazon.emr.committer.EmrOptimizedSparkSqlParquetOutputCommitter`. *This is the default setting.*

Comment: Hi Lamanus. Yes I'm explicitly stating some of the config values for clarity, even though some of the values I'm providing are the defaults. Do you believe this could have something to do with the error?

Comment: I am not sure, but it looks like that the emr related dependencies are missing.

Comment: The dependenices I am providing are for the application. Is this a missing dependency on the EMR cluster? If so do you know what the dependency is I need to provide, I haven't found it documented. Thanks!

Comment: I am just expecting that `aws-java-sdk-emr`. It is unclear, sorry man.

Comment: No worries. I tried adding `aws-java-sdk-emr` with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the spark jobs being submitted by a remote EC2 instance to the EMR master.

3 changes had to be made to allow the committer to be enabled:

- The jars on the EMR master at `/usr/lib/spark/jars/hadoop*` needed to be copied to the remote instance at `/opt/spark/jars`. In particular the hadoop jars suffxied with `-amzn`.
- All files in the EMR Master instance under `/etc/spark/conf` needed to be copied to the remote instance at `/etc/spark/conf`. The files include the EMR Master node IP, otherwise the rest of the contents of the files are predictable and template-able.
- Finally we had to ensure that the Linux OS username we used had access to HDFS. For us this required changing HADOOP_USER_NAME from *spark* to *hadoop*.

With these changes we see in the EMR cluster config:

```
**EMRFS consistent view:** Enabled
```

To utilise the `EmrOptimizedSparkSqlParquetOutputCommitter`, preventing `_temporary` directories being initially written to S3, the *When the EMRFS S3-optimized Committer is Not Used* section of [Requirements for the EMRFS S3-Optimized Committer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-committer-reqs.html)
 must be followed.

Answer (score 2):

The class can be found in the jar: /usr/share/aws/emr/goodies/lib/emr-spark-goodies-$version.jar